# Tooltip for a User-Set URL

Tags: forms, design-patterns, input-fields, tooltips

I'm dealing with a situation where we have a place for a user-entered URL/hostname after entering and re-entering their password. I've attached an image of what we're considering below. What I'm worried about is that users won't be able to tell that Custom URL is an editable field.

One suggestion I've made is that the form field doesn't need contain the ".yoururl.com" inside it. The other one is to have the question mark icon that I've added to the image, which would have a tooltip explaining what the purpose of the field is.

Basically we're wanting to make sure that users know this is an editable field. Any thoughts?

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 6):

**If `.yoururl.com` is not editable, it should be removed from the *input bar*.**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB6fxz.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Give an example to reinforce what the expected input is and also, if you want, what the output will look like.

---

On second thought, you can **let the user type in the entire URL**. URL parsing isn't a complicated problem. You can figure out the custom part of the URL in the background.

Comment: +1 but I'd even go a step further: don't add the fixed bit at the end of the text edit, but name the text edit for what it is "friendly name" or whatever and display the effect close to the edit with just the resultant text. Ie "People will be able to find you at 'yourbit.yoururl.com'"

Answer (score 1):

If the primary task for user is to create custom URL and

> What I'm worried about is that users won't be able to tell that Custom URL is an editable field

then:

1. Make this field first, not the last, as it's primary task.
2. Make it autofocused.
3. If you already have some info from user (name, email), set initial field value as user name, not the dummy newaccount. Smart defaults!